# Passar conteúdo do banco de dados de uma página para outra

Tags: banco-de-dados, angularjs, ionic, sqlite, apache-cordova

Parece ser algo simples de se pesquisar, mas não estou conseguindo. Eu gostaria de quando clicado em um item da lista, abrir uma nova página com as informações detalhadas desse item, vai ser as mesmas informações usadas na página inicial. Mas não sei como posso fazer isso. Criei uma página apenas, mas preciso receber o conteudo de cada item clicado nela.
[image: Lista de itens]

[image: Conteudo quando clicado]

Fiz um botão e quando clico vai pra pagina, so preciso receber os dados lá. Não postei o código pq nao sei exatamente qual parte do codigo postar aqui, mas se alguem puder me ajudar e precisar, só me falar. Eu quero receber as mesmas informações na segunda página, porém do item selecionado.  Obrigado!

html page1  `<ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let produto of produtos" no-padding>
            <h3 class="nomproduto"> {{produto.nom_produto}} </h3>`

ts page 1

`this.navCtrl.push(ConteudoprodutoPage, {valor: "{produto.nom_produto}"} )`

ts page 2

```
  export class ConteudoprodutoPage {

  valor ="";


 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
 this.valor = this.navParams.get("valor");
  }
```

html page 2  `<ion-card-header>
            {{produto.nom_produto}}
        </ion-card-header>`

Comment: Como você já faz para receber os conteúdos na página da lista?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como passar dados de um item selecionado numa ng-repeat para outra view](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209938/como-passar-dados-de-um-item-selecionado-numa-ng-repeat-para-outra-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode passar como parâmetro na navegação entre páginas. Esse seria o código para chamar a página seguinte:

```
this.navCtrl.push("PaginaDetalhesPage", {itemSelecionado: item});
```

Na página aberta com os detalhes, você recebe o valor da navegação:

```
this.item = navParams.get('itemSelecionado');
```

Comment: Mas o que seria o " {itemSelecionado: item}"  ?

Comment: Seria o item selecionado do ngFor na primeira página, com a lista com todos os itens.

Comment: Não vi o clique no seu html, mas acredito que você esteja passando o produto como parâmetro. Você pode passar o produto total para a página seguinte, e não só o nome. Na ts page 1: `this.navCtrl.push(ConteudoprodutoPage, {valor: produto} )`. Na ts page 2, você recebe esse parâmetro que passou como o próprio produto e não como uma variável nova. `this.produto = this.navParams.get("valor");` O `this.produto` é o que você usa no html da page 2.

Comment: Estou conseguindo receber os dados na outra página, mas tem como eu filtrar para receber apenas  do item clicado?  Ter tem, mas não sei se entendeu o que eu quis dizer. Sempre que clicar em um produto, mostrar apenas as informações dele.

Comment: Sim, no html, inclua a função de clique na linha em que você informa o ngFor: `<ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let produto of produtos" no-padding (click)="produtoSelecionado(produto)">`. Nessa função `produtoSelecionado(produto)`, chame a página seguinte, informando como parâmetro de navegação o produto que você recebeu, como eu informei anteriormente: `this.navCtrl.push(ConteudoprodutoPage, {valor: produto} )`.

Comment: e no html da page 2? se eu uso  //  <ion-card *ngFor="let produto of produtos" class="cardconteudo"> //  ele pega todos os itens, mas se eu não usar da erro

Comment: No html da página 2 você só tem o `produto`, que veio da navegação em `this.produto = this.navParams.get("valor");`. Na página 2 você não precisa ter o `produtos`. No html da página 2 você não precisa usar um ngFor, mas sim, só os dados do produto.

Comment: recebo o erro quando uso  <ion-card-header>         {{produto.nom_produto}} </ion-card-header>     na page 2.  
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom_produto' of undefined TypeError.

Comment: Você alterou no contructor para `this.produto`, onde está `this.valor`?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81952/discussion-between-felipe-xst-and-renata).

Comment: no contructor da page2 está: this.produtos = this.navParams.get("valor"); 
e no click da page 1: 
querocomprar() { 
this.navCtrl.push(ConteudoprodutoPage, { 
valor: this.produtos 
}) 
}

Comment: estava fazendo algumas coisas erradas.  Mas consegui já, obrigado :D