# Pegar dado do Firebase e passar para uma outra página ionic

Tags: ionic, firebase

Estou exibindo uma lista de usuários, puxo do Firebase e exibo na Page Ionic, quando exibo os dados do usuário, eu coloco o ID como hidden

**Aqui eu pego os dados do Firebase**

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-thumbnail item-start>
    <img src="https://ionicframework.com/dist/preview-app/www/assets/img/thumbnail-rotla.png">
  </ion-thumbnail>

  <h2 hidden>{{f.id}}</h2>
  <h1 text-wrap><strong>{{f.nome}}</strong></h1>
  <p text-wrap><strong>{{f.cidade}}</strong></p>

<ion-item>
  <button ion-button (click)="verPessoa(f.id)" block color="primary">
    Continuar
  </button>
</ion-item>
<hr/>
```

A partir desse f.id eu preciso passar para uma outra tela para exibir apenas os dados desse usuário em particular

Comment: Apresenta algum erro quando você passa para outra tela? A função com problema é a `verPessoa`? Se for isso, inclua a função na sua pergunta.

Comment: Na verdade, esse código que mandei é da tela em que pego os dados do firebase, é exibida uma lista com todos os usuários, cada usuário tem um ID, quando eu clicar ali na função verPessoa quero ir pra outra página e só mostrar os dados desse usuário específico pois cada usuário tem um próprio botão com essa função verPessoa

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/323224/passar-conte%C3%BAdo-do-banco-de-dados-de-uma-p%C3%A1gina-para-outra/323234#323234) um exemplo de navegação entre páginas passando parâmetros.